# Odd drive under "Other" in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have this strange device under Windows Explorer in Windows 7 right now.  It's got the generic unknown file type icon, a random hex code, and I can't open it or get any properties on it.

MS Security Essentials and Malwarebytes didn't show anything worrisome, but it would be helpful if someone could explain what it is, and what it is doing there.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps add a screenshot?

Comment: Not sure how much it helps, but I added an image.

Comment: it helps :-) Right click it and try and do a properties of it, how is it different? check out the Hardware tab while your there to see the device list for that type of hardware.    Go into disk manager and see if it exists, If it exists how is it tagged? Then go into the Device manager , and see if you can find anything odd in there.   Do you have special encryption stuff, or specially encrypted devices in anything? Virus software only sees what it knows, so it is not usually helpfull. Is always better to be a observant user (you) than to be relying on something that doesnt know. (me:-)

Comment: It doesn't present me with the "Properties" option on right-click, which is what set me off initially.  I'll check the rest when I get home.  I can only try to open it, which does nothing.

Comment: Did not show up on Disk Manager, didn't see anything that stuck out in Device Manager.  I haven't done anything related to encryption on this box, so far as I can remember.

Comment: scan your registry for that hex and post the keys associated with it.

Comment: So it's under \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{c900ea2f-8575-4e86-bae9-f94620699414}, and the default icon is labeled as C:\Program Files\Droid Explorer\Assets\GT-I9000.ico.  GT-i9000 is the model for my phone, so I guess when I uninstalled that software it left the icon behind.  Thanks for the suggestion, HackToHell.

Comment: @Trevor happy to help :)

Comment: Please put that up as the answer so this question can come out of the unanswered pile.

Comment: @mischab1: Put up a community wiki, because it has been months now. A single vote will get it of the unanswered pile.

Answer (score 2):

The questioner mentioned:

> So it's under \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{c900ea2f-8575-4e86-bae9-f94620699414}, and the default icon is labeled as C:\Program Files\Droid Explorer\Assets\GT-I9000.ico. GT-i9000 is the model for my phone, so I guess when I uninstalled that software it left the icon behind.